# Image clipped and appended at the start of frame in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, stream

So here I am again, unsure what to do..
I have two threads.
One that fills the queue with images after converting them to 24rgb bitmap.
2nd to read those images and stream them to a video device.
Other than this i have a graphics object, the queue maintains bitmap of images. I am using two streams.
In the destructor of the class i dispose all of the data and abort threads.
Still the video that i get at the output is clipped and a bit of image data that should be at the end of frame, comes at the start of frame.
My question is i have disposed streams, cleared queue,disposed graphics object, aborted threads. What possible am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong, instead for gathering bytes from stream, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101087/inverted-image-in-c).
The problem with the stream method is that it somehow gets the garbage data too.